# how to define pipes in angular 2 template tag

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am using template tag  for using functionality of angular 1 **ng-repeat-start** and **ng-repeat-end**.It works fine but do not understand how I declare pipes in it.So please help me.

```
<template ngFor let-customer [ngForOf]="customers" let-customerIndex="index">
```

In this I want to put `| customfilter:value | paginate:{itemsPerPage:4, currentPage: p}`

Comment: Did `[ngForOf]="customers | customfilter:value | paginate:{itemsPerPage:4, currentPage: p}"` not work?

Comment: its works.thanx

Comment: I used it before but its not working because of other issue but in this time its works for me.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer, if it solved your problem, so this question can be solved as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your pipes simply in the existing `ngForOf` binding like you would on a regular `ngFor`:

```
[ngForOf]="customers | customfilter:value | paginate:{itemsPerPage:4, currentPage: p}"
```